# Adding header rows to Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, datasource, dataview

My gridview is similar to this:

> ```
> 12- CategoryA - other columns
> 13- CategoryA - other columns
> 14- CategoryA - other columns
> 15- CategoryA - other columns
>
> 16- CategoryB - other columns
> 17- CategoryB - other columns
> 18- CategoryB - other columns
> ```

What I want is smthing like that:

```
CategoryA (colspan 2) 
12 - other columns 
13 - other columns 
14 - other columns 
15 - other columns 
Category B (colspan 2) 
16 - other columns
17 - other columns 
18 - other columns
```

Can I do this by modifing the datatable which I bind as datasource ? Or is there an easier way ?

Comment: Is your `gridview` in a `ListView`?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Sorry I did not understand?

Comment: Can you post some part of your XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event is what you'll need. You can keep track of what previous category was shown and what category will be shown.

```
class MyClass
{
    private string CurrentCategory{ get; set; }

    // Load_Page with databinding the GridView{  }

    protected void mygridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
          (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["mycolumn"].ToString() != CurrentCategory))
        {
            GridViewRow tr = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex +1, e.Row.RowIndex + 1, 
                                   DataControlRowType.DataRow, e.Row.RowState);
            TableCell newTableCell = new TableCell();
            newTableCell.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["mycolumn"].ToString();
            CurrentCategory = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["mycolumn"].ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(newTableCell);

            ((Table)e.Row.Parent).Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Code is provided as-is and not tested.

Comment: this seem to work with a little modification, it adds titles, but underneath of rows. Can you modify it please? I don't know gridviewrow parameters works

Comment: The wonders of the internets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.gridviewrow.aspx

Comment: What you'd need to alter is the RowIndex: Instead of e.Row.RowIndex+1, leave the '+1'

Answer (score 0):

The GridView control does not support grouping natively.

Comment: I am not trying to group it automatically, I am trying to group it manually.